# How to "copy-paste" blocks of text from one file to another using python?

Tags: python, text, text-processing

I am running some molecular simulations, and I have a file with coordinates (a .xyz file, which is basically a file with tabbed columns)  and I need to send it another file, which will be my input file for my simulation.

To give you a picture, this is how my input files look like with my coordinates (there is more stuff at the bottom that remains untouched):
`inputfile.py`

```
# One-electron Properties
# Methacrylic acid (MA0)
# Neutral
# 86.09 g/mol
memory 8 GB
molecule MA0 {
0 1
  C          2.87618       -0.84254        0.16797
  C          2.96148        0.13611        1.08491
  C          2.43047       -0.01082        2.47698
  C          3.62022        1.40750        0.67356
  O          3.45819        2.47668        1.24567
}
.
.
.
```

I have generated some coordinates which are in another file. That file looks like:
`conformer_coords.xyz`

```
15
conformer index = 0001, molecular weight is = 100.052429496, MMA.pdb
O          2.98687        0.35207        1.05259
C          2.40900        0.04400        0.02100
O          1.13058        0.37171       -0.29283
C          0.85476        1.77012       -0.33847
.
.
.
```

What I want to do is replace the coordinates in `inputfile.py` to the coordinates in `conformer_coords.xyz`. The number of coordinate positions in my conformer is known. Let's call it `N` for now. So, `conformer_coords.xyz` has N+2 lines.

I basically want to take coordinates from `conformer_coords.xyz` and place them between the

```
{
0 1
```

and `}` (yes, the `0 1` are needed there).

How should I go about this? Can python pull it off? I am using subprocess anyway, so if awk or bash can do it, I would be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction!!

Comment: Do you need to do this once or a bunch of times? If just once, would copy+paste work?

Comment: Yes, I have to do this a bunch of times. I have like 1000 conformers, which I need to test lol @mackorone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re
def insert_data(conformer_filepath,input_filepath,output_filepath):
    #grab conformer data
    with open(conformer_filepath,'r') as f:
        conformer_text = f.read()
    conformer_data = re.search('conformer[^\n]+\n(.+)',conformer_text,re.M|re.S).group(1)
    #this looks for the line that has conformer in it and takes all lines after it
    
    #grab input file before and after text
    with open(input_filepath,'r') as f:
        input_text = f.read()
    input_pre,input_post = re.search('(^.+\n0 1\n).+?(\n}.*)$',input_text,re.M|re.S).groups()
    #this looks for the "0 1" line and takes everything before that. Then it skips down to the next curly bracket which is at the start of a line and takes that and everything past it.

    #write them to the output file
    with open(output_filepath,'w') as f:
        f.write(input_pre + conformer_data + input_post)
        #this writes the three pieces collected to the output file
```